# How to speed up EOS node synchronization with the Mainnet

Tags: mainnet, node, full-node

I'm trying to set up a non-producing node for my application to query data from the EOS blockchain.

I started synchronizing for three days. However, only five million blocks have been downloaded so far.

It appears that blocks are produced faster than they are being downloaded to my node.

I used the peers from [privex.io](https://eosnodes.privex.io/?config=1) to synchronize with my local node.

My hardware specifications are:

Virtual CPU Core: 2

RAM: 8GB

Disk Space: 100 GB

Any advice on how to speed up the node synchronization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOS Nation Snapshots: https://snapshots.eosnation.io/

Also Sw/Eden: https://snapshots.eossweden.org/

We also keep this updated to get peers, genesis, etc: https://docs.liquidapps.io/en/stable/dsps/eosio-node.html

Comment: there's this service for this https://eosnode.tools/blocks

Comment: All these are now not working.

Comment: this works: https://snapshots.eosnation.io/ and https://snapshots.eossweden.org/

Comment: Hi @Nat can you please add some reference or a tutorial where it explained how to start a mainnet node using snapshot? This will be a great help

Comment: Yes we have a tutorial here: https://docs.liquidapps.io/en/stable/dsps/eosio-node.html.  You can message me on Telegram if you have an issue @natpd

Answer (score 0):

Even with the tar ball from eosnode.tools it takes forever to sync up. I am running nodeeos on a 32GB system and it went on for days. I even wrote a script to estimate how long it takes to sync up.

[See my related question and answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/how-can-i-verify-if-my-node-is-synced-up-to-the-head-of-the-blockchain)